# Pushing and popping values for each button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

On each button click, the value should be pushed into array and shown to the div.
If clicked again it should be popped out from array and removed from div as well.

I am toggling a Boolean value for this, but the popped values are not removed from the div when Boolean is false, perhaps something i am doing wrong.
Project can be edited [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQPEASMK7YQO)

```js
$( "#button-list button" ).each(function(index) {
var items = [];
var toggle = false;
    $(this).on("click", function(){
    toggle = !toggle;
    if(toggle === true)
    items.push(this.value);
    else
    items.pop(this.value);
    
      $("#results").append(items);      
 });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button-list">
<button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(1,1)">(1,1)</button>
<button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(2,2)">(2,2)</button>
<button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(3,4)">(3,4)</button>
<button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(5,2)">(5,2)</button>
<button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(3,1)">(3,1)</button>
</div>
<p id="results"></p>
```

Comment: 1 click to the p tag, 2nd click popped from both div and p tag?

Comment: The items array is scoped too low.  Each button has it's own array.

Comment: Yeah you need to set var items = []; outside the loop

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQPEASMK7YQO

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop  Also pop does not take an argument.  It always removes the last element.

Comment: @Taplar is that possible to push them in one array ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041501/pushing-multiple-button-values-to-a-single-array

Comment: @GragasIncoming both the answers below manipulate a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 Small changes

1. Declare items outside of the `each()` function. If not it resets for each listener
2. Change the `append()` function for `text()`.

Append will add the items on each click. You want to replace the items on each click.

3. `pop()` will remove the last element from the array. You need to use `splice()`. Splice recieves 2 values. First the index you want to remove, the the amount of element to remove.

using `indexOf()` we can get the element index on the array.

```
items.splice(items.indexOf(this.value), 1);
```

Hope this helps :)

```js
var items = [];
$("#button-list button").each(function(index) {
  var toggle = false;
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    toggle = !toggle;
    if (toggle === true)
      items.push(this.value);
    else
      items.splice(items.indexOf(this.value), 1);

    //console.log(items);
    $("#results").text(items);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button-list">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(1,1)">(1,1)</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(2,2)">(2,2)</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(3,4)">(3,4)</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(5,2)">(5,2)</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(3,1)">(3,1)</button>
</div>
<p id="results"></p>
```

Comment: there is one issue not popping out but popping, with the first element in the array

Comment: I edited for splice() so you can remove the element you want to remove

Answer (score 0):

```js
var items = [];

$("#button-list button").on('click', function(e){
  var indexOfElement = items.indexOf(e.target.value);
  //value is not in the array
  if (indexOfElement < 0) {
    items.push(e.target.value);
  } else {
    //value is in the array, remove it
    items.splice(indexOfElement, 1);
  }
  
  $('#results').text(items);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button-list">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(1,1)">(1,1)</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(2,2)">(2,2)</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(3,4)">(3,4)</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(5,2)">(5,2)</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black" value="(3,1)">(3,1)</button>
</div>
<p id="results"></p>
```